# calling python script from PHP import module error

Tags: php, python, python-import

I have this python script that i need to call it from php,
this my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import dlib
import sys
import os
import cv2
from shutil import copyfile

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Test"
```

this is my php code to call python script:

```
<?php
$out =  shell_exec("/usr/bin/python2.7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/test.py");
echo $out;
?>
```

My problem is the python code works perfectly from terminal, but using php he doesn't work because of `import dlib` when i delete it the python script works fine from php and when i add it he doesn't work.

The dlib libray works perfectly since when i test the python code from terminal he works.

Comment: what's the error you get? I have sometimes written tracebacks to a file inside a try-except block when the script I was calling was being called by a parent process that didn't nicely pass stderr along.

Comment: there is ni output when i run with dlib imported but what i think is a directory permesion becuase when i change the python script folder to desktop i can run it!